# Manipulate Pandas dataframe based on index and column values

Tags: pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe (in code):

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame([['ID1', 4], ['ID1', 4], ['ID1', 4], ['ID2', 5], ['ID2', 5], ['ID2', 5], ['ID3', 6], ['ID3', 6], ['ID3', 6]], columns=['Index', 'Value'])
```

Based on each occurence of the **change** in Index value, only the first value column's integer should be maintained, and the rest of the values should be changed to 0 value.

The resulting manipulated dataframe should look like this:

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame([['ID1', 4], ['ID1', 0], ['ID1', 0], ['ID2', 5], ['ID2', 0], ['ID2', 0], ['ID3', 6], ['ID3', 0], ['ID3', 0]], columns=['Index', 'Value'])
```

I have tried numerous different manipulation techniques, but none has worked. I have tried substitution of values, but this doesn't scale well for many rows at once. Please could someone provide any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `0` for all values if difference with next row [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
mask = original_df['Index'].ne(original_df['Index'].shift())
original_df['Value'] = original_df['Value'].where(mask, 0)
```

Or use:

```
mask = original_df['Index'].ne(original_df['Index'].shift())
original_df['Value'] = np.where(mask, original_df['Value'], 0)
```

---

```
print (original_df)  
  Index  Value
0   ID1      4
1   ID1      0
2   ID1      0
3   ID2      5
4   ID2      0
5   ID2      0
6   ID3      6
7   ID3      0
8   ID3      0
```

If groups are sorted is possible use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
mask = original_df['Index'].duplicated()
original_df['Value'] = original_df['Value'].mask(mask, 0)
original_df['Value'] = np.where(mask, 0, original_df['Value'])
```